# Polyline offset with closed polygon and islands

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have unsorted set of line segments without any binding to each other. Each line described with 2 points (x,y). I can search for lines with the same points, which means they should be connected.

Every line have a thickness attribute.  I need to offset each path by this thickness, and create 4 points describing the final plygon (for each line).

[Screenshot 1](https://sites.google.com/site/dusanmaliarik/screenshot1.png)

now I need to refine it to handle corners (joins) correctly. but have no idea how to do it.

Desired result: [Screenshot 2](https://sites.google.com/site/dusanmaliarik/screenshot2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Straight_skeleton_2/Chapter_main.html) for one method of offsetting a polygon using it's skeleton (which is what you are trying to do here).

Comment: thanks! now only thing that I need are some Ruby bindings for CGAL