# Deformed object after 2d rotation

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 2d, vector-graphics

I have certain objects in a 2D plane.I'm using a drawing techonology(drawing visuals) which draws the elements like it pushes them on a stack,first element is on the bottom second - on top of it and so on.Now,the problem is that I need all objects, except one of them(the background), on the same Z level because in the current state that my program is it happens to rotate in a sort of 3D way everything and it is supposed to rotate it in a 2D way.I understand that this explanation is NOT good that's why please refer to the images below.

Before rotating by theta angle : [image]
After rotating by a theta angle : [image]

You can see how the two lines start to overlap and this mustn't happen.They do get closer to each other as I rotate the figure and there's a certain angle where the two lines become fully overlapped and they look like one line.I want to avoid that.

The forumlae that I use for the rotation:

```
        foreach(var item in Visuals){
           var p = new Point(item.Position.X - center.X, item.Position.Y - center.Y);
           var xnew = p.X * cos - p.Y * sin;
           var ynew = p.X * sin + p.Y * cos;
           p.X = xnew + center.X;
           p.Y = ynew + center.Y;
           item.Update(p.X, p.Y);
        }
```

This is how I get the sin and cos of the angle

```
     var pos = new Point(position.Y - center.Y, position.X - center.X);
     var rad = Math.Atan2(pos.Y, pos.X);
     var deg = rad.ToDegrees();
     var diff = RotationLastAngle - deg;//The last angle that we rotated to.
     RotationLastAngle = deg;
     var ans = diff.ToRadians();
     Host.Representation.Rotate(Math.Cos(ans), Math.Sin(ans), center);
```

`Update()` basically sets the coordinates of `item` in a single line.

What I think is causing the issue is that the DrawingVisual renders items on layers and thus one of the lines is higher than the other one(Correct me if I'm wrong).I need to find a way to avoid this.

This is how I draw the lines :

```
                    var dx = FromAtom.Atom.X - ToAtom.Atom.X;
                    var dy = FromAtom.Atom.Y - ToAtom.Atom.Y;
                    var slope = dy / dx;
                    if (slope > 0)
                    {
                        context.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, Thickness), new Point(FromAtom.Position.X + 3, FromAtom.Position.Y + 3), new Point(ToAtom.Position.X + 3, ToAtom.Position.Y + 3));
                        context.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, Thickness), new Point(FromAtom.Position.X - 3, FromAtom.Position.Y - 3), new Point(ToAtom.Position.X - 3, ToAtom.Position.Y - 3));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, Thickness), new Point(FromAtom.Position.X + 3, FromAtom.Position.Y - 3), new Point(ToAtom.Position.X + 3, ToAtom.Position.Y - 3));
                        context.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, Thickness), new Point(FromAtom.Position.X - 3, FromAtom.Position.Y + 3), new Point(ToAtom.Position.X - 3, ToAtom.Position.Y + 3));
                    }
```

Taken from Adam Nathan's WPF 4.5 Unleashed says : "

> Later drawings are placed on top of earlier drawings,so they preserve proper Z ordering

which refers to `GeometryDrawing` but I think this holds for drawing lines too.

Comment: So what is the problem. It is not clear from the pictures what you expected. You code does a rotation about the plane, this is the results you get.

Comment: In normal rotation in 2D you don't normally get overlapping lines.The reason for the overlap is because one of the lines has depth lower than the other one.

Comment: Please explain. A rotation does not deform the shape and in the pictures above it shows exactly that. What overlapping lines are you talking about? Please show clearly what you get and what you expect (with another sketch).

Comment: I have updated with more appropriate images.

Comment: If I apply a rotate transform in C# it works as expected.So there must be something with the formula.

Comment: What values are in sin and cos? Also: could you post the code of Update? It might be that you are not updating all points (and thereby moving the lines)

Comment: Your rotation is fine for clockwise rotation when positive _y_ is downwards, or anti-clockwise rotation when positive _y_ is upwards. What is your convention here?

Comment: Yes,the convention is exactly as you described it.I have added further information about the problem @ErnodeWeerd.

Comment: Um,I mean when positive y is downwards.Hehe.

Comment: How can you update (rotate) all points of a Visual by passing one new position to Update?

Comment: I've slightly changed to code sample to include the foreach statement.

Comment: @ja72 I was wondering if it could be the drawing visual's system that is the problem because as you said this rotation shouldn't be causing deformations..

Comment: What is not clear is the _intent_ of the code. What are you trying to achieve here? Can you store angles directly instead of deducing them from positions? Why convert back and forth between `deg` and `rad`, just keep things in radians and use a property to display degrees if needed.

Comment: @ja72 I used this so I can remember what I meant to do when I go back to the code.Anyway what this achieves is a rotation of a specific degree derived by the position of the mouse,where the position variable in the second sample is the current position of the mouse.

Comment: So like an [tag:arcball] calculation with a 3D to 2D projection?

Comment: @ja72 No,the problem has nothing to do with projection from 3D to 2D.The problem is that after I perform the rotation explained above I get 3 dimensional look because the DrawingVisual's method RenderOpen draws on a something that works like stack, it draws the objects from lowest height up to higher so it basically adds a Z index to the 2D plane which is what I'm trying to avoid because you can imagine when I rotate the object one of the lines goes above the other one and it hides it.Hope I  was clear but if it didn't made enough sense to you be welcome to ask.I appreciate it!

Comment: What you haven't shown is the code that draws the lines and how the `Z` index affects the position. As is there isn't enough information to reproduce the problem and hence no effective solution can be proposed.

Comment: @ja72 I have updated my question further.

Comment: @ja72 There is no Z index.The problem is that DrawingVisual renders the object ontop of each other and I'm not completely sure but I think this is why there is this depth that is appearing(which acts as the Z index but I have no access to)

Comment: This is frustrating, you mention z index and then say there isn't a z index? I also added the [tag:wpf].

Comment: @ja72 There is not actual Z index that I can interact with.It's managed by the way 'DrawingContext' renders items.

Comment: What is the intent of the `+3` and `-3` in the drawing code? This is what the problem is I think.

Comment: + 3 - 3 causes the lines to be drawn in parallel depending on the slope of the lines

Comment: That is where the code fails. The parallel offset needs to be rotated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the result fails because you are offsetting the lines by 3 pixels vertically or horizontally with no consideration of the actual orientation of the line. The offset vector needs to be rotated with the line in order to achieve this effect. The problem then is that the lines will not meet together and have gaps or overlaps. To solve that problem you will need some math.

Drawing a parallel lines (or polygon) is not a trivial problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462037/380384) answer for how to do it, but it your case you might be able to use [compound lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.compoundarray(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Parallel Line Example**

[image: Form]

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer.Never thought that could've been the issue,THANK YOU!